# Jquery: How to get value from a new checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a jquery to add a new checkbox when I click an option from an existing checkbox.

Next I add an id in this checkbox and I want to get it's value through a new jquery.

My current html code is:

```
<div id="div_id_diag-diagnosis_option" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_diag-diagnosis_option_0" class="control-label col-md-3 requiredField">Option<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class="controls col-md-8">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_1" value="b">b</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_2" value="a">a</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_3" value="c">c</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery to add the checkbox is:

```
$("input[name='diag-diagnosis_option']").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.prop('checked')) {
        var option = $(this).val();
        alert(option);
        $(this).parent().append("<a href='#'>here</a>");
    } else if ($this.siblings('a').length) {
        $this.siblings('a').remove();
    }
});
```

The jquery to get the value of the new checkbox is the one below but it's not working:

```
$('#extended').change(function() {
    var option = $(this).val();
    alert(option);
});
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zinonas/Luskw0nu/).

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change','#extended',function () {
        var option = $(this).val();
        alert(option);
    });
```

Use `.on()` because you are adding it dynamically

> Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/Luskw0nu/3/)
[docu](https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=_IEcVtWlF4zI8AeL-IXwDw&gws_rd=ssl#q=.on%20jquery)

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: glad it helped.you can tick the check to make it the correct answer